# Make variable available on web page after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a button that lives on a web page. When it is clicked the following happens:

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click26(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hidCar = "26";
    string url = string.Format("Beta.aspx?year={0}&track={1}&event={2}&car={4}&session{3}", hidYear.Value, hidTrack.Value, hidEvent.Value, hidSession.Value, hidCar);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

The page then navigates from one web form ("default.aspx") to a different form ("beta.aspx"). My issue is that my `hidCar` variable is now unavailable to use once I have navigated to the "beta.aspx" page. What is the best practice to get this variable available on the new page?

Comment: There are multiple options: 1. Session 2. MemoryCache 3. QueryString (pass the value in your url), 4. Application Variables. 5. HttpContext

Comment: QueryString seems very helpful for my case. If you can make a full answer I can give you credit.

Comment: You're example is already passing it in the query string -> `&car={4} , hidCar)`. I'm not sure what help you need me to provide? If you need help retrieving this value: (https://forums.asp.net/t/1203508.aspx?Access+QueryString+Object+in+ASPX+Page)